# Thermotrophy: An open-ended question

Tags: creature-design, fauna, flora

Something I've been thinking about recently is the viability of thermotrophic organisms - that is, organisms that are able to obtain energy by absorbing heat, and then - by some mechanism or process - are able to use that heat to produce more energy. Of course, this is rather impossible - but let's pretend that it is for a moment. What I'd like to ask other world-builders is, what dubiously possible niches/body plans do you suggest complex thermotrophic life would or could develop, and - if you really want to go in depth - how would *you* say that thermotrophy is conducted? Would you think it's a process similar to, say, photosynthesis - or something entirely different?

Comment: We're not a site for open ended questions. Questions that are intended to prompt discussion and solicit opinions are explicitly prohibited.

Comment: I am digging thermotrophy but sphennings is right.  This is too broad.   It even confesses the fact in the title.   Maybe you can ask a series of questions about thermotrophy, each building on the last.

Comment: Tbh, if it didn't outright state in the title "an open-ended question", I think this would fly just like any other question on this stack. We get questions like this all the time, i.e., "how would my organism do x function?"

Comment: We have [entire ecosystems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrothermal_vent#Biology_of_hydrothermal_vents) here on Earth which are powered by thermal gradients.

Comment: There are two questions in one :) : How would they look like and how thermotrophy would work. Both on their own are a bit too broad. You should indeed cut the topic into smaller, more digestible pieces, yummy !

Comment: Related and worth a read (before you narrow and clarify) on our biology sister-stack: [Is infrared photosynthesis possible?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/17147/is-infrared-photosynthesis-possible), links to the interesting discovery of [Chlorophyll F](https://www.wired.com/2010/08/infrared-chlorophyl/).

Comment: I suggest some non-fiction books by Nick Lane : The Vital Question , Oxygen , and Transformer .  He describes several kinds of gradients that Earth life uses for its essential chemistries, and you can fit that into novel niches in your worlds.  I also suggest the Camelot 30k and other books by Robert L. Forward for some novel speculative niches for life.

Comment: Just to nail down the point, the [help/dont-ask] specifically forbids open-ended, hypothetical questions. Please take the time to read the following two Help Center pages to better understand the limits of what we're willing to accept: [help/on-topic] and [help/dont-ask]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As scientists were cleaning the outside of *Magmarine-I* (the first vessel to bring humans to the outer core), they couldn't help but notice a cool sensation when they placed their hands on its hull. After careful microscopic examination, they discovered the magmarine's hull was covered with extremophiles.

These heat-eating thermotrophs apparently thrived in the [200C-4000C environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_mantle#Temperature_and_pressure) mantle using a complex process that would later be termed predictive synchronization. This process capitalizes on the principle that photons from a 'randomly' moving atom usually reach the collision target nanoseconds before the electron clouds actually exchange kinetic energy. By amplifying this information before a collision occurs, thermotrophs have a brief window where they can effectively become [Maxwell's deamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon).

There are many kinds of thermotrophs, but all prokaryotic ones share two structural motifs: 1) their cell wall is covered in predictive synchronase complexes (PSC's), and 2) much of their cytoplasmic volume is occupied by an internal network of oscillitase-$\beta$.

PSC's are a family of protein complexes that include a light harvesting complex, predictase, and several *oscillitase-$\alpha$* filaments which are each terminated by impactase. They're structured like this:

[image: Highly professional depiction of a Predictive Synchronase Complex (PSC)]

[Light harvesting complexes (LHC's)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-harvesting_complexes_of_green_plants) are enzymes that capture energy from absorbed photons. Though LHC's typically feed into a reaction complex to perform photosynthesis, they [have been applied in artificial photochemical conversion](https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/jp038036b#), so it seems reasonable that thermotrophs could perform something similar for photon detection. The individual enzymes of the LHC in PSC's are hemispherically-aranged, which enables the PSC to determine the overall electromagnetic gradient (which preceeds the kinetic energy gradient). However given that liquids have a mean time to collision in the femtoseconds[^2] while [the electron transfer from antanea chlorophyll is around 3 orders of magnitude slower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photosynthesis#Order_and_kinetics), the PSC doesn't stand a chance of beating the thermokinetic energy front unless it utilizes some additional tricks. That's why most PSC's also include a spagetti-like enzyme known as *predictase*. This modecule fills a computational role similar to that of [Roger Penrose's description of the microtubules in neurons](https://legacy.cs.indiana.edu/classes/b629-sabr/QuantumComputationInBrainMicrotubules.pdf): individual monomers in the network each function as a qubit and the network as a whole entangles to perform terahertz-frequency processing (excuse me for paraphrasing). With this computational budget at its disposall, predictase is able to store and simulate a primitive representation of the brownian force fields acting on its PSC's receptor area and use that simulation to predict from what direction the majority of molecules are likely to strike from and the optimal protein folding response to minimize destructive interference. Additionally, given the observation of quantum entanglement at a protein complex scale, we would not be surprise if these scientists later discover that the entire PSC complex is entangled such that it can exploit some kind of  [delayed choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delayed-choice_quantum_eraser#Delayed_choice) or [retrocausality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrocausality#Quantum_physics) to maximize its liklihood of success.

The actual physical responsibility of constructively absorbing thermo-kinetic energy falls on impactase-terminated *oscillitase-$\alpha$* strands. *oscillitase-$\alpha$* has long thin mostly-saturated hydrocarbon filaments that vibrate such that their terminal end naturally resonates with the substrate solution (the mantle's magma). Hevier $\mathrm{Fe}$ and $\mathrm{Co}$ metalloproteins known as *impactase* terminate these strands, and their mass eases the demand for a high *oscillitase* spring coefficient (which would require more complex, higher friction polymers) Finally, the whole oscillitase-$\alpha$-impactase subcomplex is under extreme conditions and denatures in a few minutes, but thermotrophs deal with this by retracting and repairing the oscillitase-$\alpha$-impactase subcomplex every few minutes. The subcomplex of the PSC looks like this (note the long thin hydrocarbon strands):

[image: oscillitase-alpha-impactase subcomplex]

> If you're a prokaryote reading this and you'd like to try out these enzymes yourself, just install the following base bair sequences into your genome:
>
> ```
> #!/bin/env python3
> # thermotroph.py
>
> import sys
> from synbio import make_split, make_sticky_end # not a real library atm   
>
> # DNA for photosystem II P680 chlorophyll A apoprotein (used for the LHC antannae)
> # https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/5955338
> P680 = 'ATGGGTTTGCCTTGGTATCGTGTGCATACCGTCGTATTGAATGATCCTGGCCGTTTGCTGGCTGTCCATA TAATGCATACAGCTTTGGTTGCTGGTTGGGCCGGTTCGATGGCTTTATATGAATTAGCCGTTTTTGATCC CTCTGACCCCGTTCTTGATCCAATGTGGAGACAAGGTATGTTCGTTATACCCTTCATGACTCGTTTAGGA ATAACTAATTCATGGGGTGGTTGGAGTATCACAGGGGGAACTGTAACGAATCCGGGTATTTGGAGTTACG AAGGTGTGGCCGGCTCACATATTCTGTTTTCTGGCTTGTGCTTCTTGGCAGCTATCTGGCATTGGGTGTA TTGGGATTTAGCAATATTTTCTGATGAACGCACAGGAAAACCTTCTTTAGATTTGCCCAAGATCTTTGGA ATTCATTTATTTCTTTCAGGGCTAGCTTGCTTTGGTTTTGGCGCATTTCATGTAACAGGGTTGTATGGTC CTGGAATCTGGGTGTCCGATCCTTATGGACTAACTGGAGAGGTACAACCTGTAAATCCAGCATGGGGCGT ...'
>
> # DNA for fatty acid synthase, a precursor to oscillitase-alpha
> # https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=g.17924A%3EG
> FASN = 'GTCAGCCCATGTGGCGTGTCCGCACGGGGACGGCCGCGGTTAAATAGCGCCGGCGCGGGCCTAGAGGGAG CCAGAGAGACAGTAGCGGCCTCTCCTCCACCGCACACTCCATCCTCGCTCTCCCTCAGCCGTTCGCACAG CCGCCCGCGCCCAGACCAGGTACAAGCGGCCAGGCCGGGCCGGGGTCGGAAGTTGCGAGTCGGGAACCCG GTCCTGGGGCCAGACTGGATCGGGGGCTGGGGCGGGAGCAAGGCGGCCGGGCTCGAGCGGGCGCCGCCGG CCCGCATCCTCTGGCCTTGGGTGCGCATGGTTCGGCGCGCTGATGGTGAGGGCTCATCTCACACAGCCTG CCCTGGTCTCGGCGTCCGAGCCTCCGGTCTGGATGTTCGAGCCCCACGAGACGCCCGAGGCTAGGCGGCA AAGGGCCCTCGCGCCATGCCTAAGCCCAGCGAGGCAGGTGGGCGGATAGCGAGGGGCGGACGCCCGGGAA CGCCGCGAACAGCCATTTTGGTCTTGGACTGGGCCGGGCGGCTGCGGACCCTCGAGGGCCTGTTGGAGCC ...'
>
> # DNA for producing microtubules (which produces predictase)
> ## microtubule associated protein tau catylizes tubulin self-assembly
> ## https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/4137
> MAPT = 'GCAGTCACCGCCACCCACCAGCTCCGGCACCAACAGCAGCGCCGCTGCCACCGCCCACCTTCTGCCGCCG CCACCACAGCCACCTTCTCCTCCTCCGCTGTCCTCTCCCGTCCTCGCCTCTGTCGACTATCAGGTAAGCG CCGCGGCTCCGAAATCTGCCTCGCCGTCCGCCTCTGTGCACCCCTGCGCCGCCGCCCCTCGCCCTCCCTC TCCGCAGACTGGGGCTTCGTGCGCCGGGCATCGGTCGGGGCCACCGCAGGGCCCCTCCCTGCCTCCCCTG CTCGGGGGCTGGGGCCAGGGCGGCCTGGAAAGGGACCTGAGCAAGGGATGCACGCACGCGTGAGTGCGCG CGTGTGTGTGTGCTGGAGGGTCTTCACCACCAGATTCGCGCAGACCCCAGGTGGAGGCTGTGCCGGCAGG GTGGGGCGCGGCGGCGGTGACTTGGGGGAGGGGGCTGCCCTTCACTCTCGACTGCAGCCTTTTGCCGCAA TGGGCGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGTGGAGGGGTCCGATAACGACCCCC ...'
> ## tubulin alpha 1b and 1c monomers respectively
> ## https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/10376 
> TUBA1B = 'AGTGCGTTACTTACCTCGACTCTTAGCTTGTCGGGGACGGTAACCGGGACCCGGTGTCTGCTCCTGTCGC CTTCGCCTCCTAATCCCTAGCCACTATGGTGAGTAAGCCGTGCGGCTCCCGGCTGCTTTCAGGGAAGCAG GGAAAAGCGAGCCGGCGGGGCGCTGGGGCCCTGTATACAGCCGGGAAGGGCTGGCCTCAGAGCCGTCCGT TTGGAGGGCGGAAAACGAGGCGAGAGGCCAGGGCGGGAGTGGTGAGACCTCGGTGTGTGTAAATAGCGGG GGCCCGGAAAGGTCGAGGGGCGCCAGGATTTCTTCTCGGACTCTGGAAGGGATGGGGGGCTCGGGCTGCC CTCCGCCGTATCCGGAGCTCTCTTTTGTCGCGTAACTGTGTCCTGGGTGCGGTCCCTCGAGTCCCCGCAG TCCTTTCCAGCGCATGCCCTTACTCCGCCTTGGGTGGACGCGCGCGCGGACTCTTCCAGCCCTCACTTCC TCTTGAGCGCGAAAAGCGGGGGTGGGAAGCAGCTGGAGACAAAAGCGCGCACGCGCGACCGTTACCTTCC ...'
> ## https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/84790
> TUBA1C = 'AAGTGAACAATGGGCGCCCAGCTCTAAAATGACAGCCTGGTTCAATGGGGTGGAGGAGCTAGGGAGGGAT GAGTGCTTTGTGTGCTTGGAATTAGATCCTTCAAATGGATCCTTTCTGAATGCAAAACTGTACATCTCTA ACTGGATTCTTATTTACTTCACCAGGACTCTTCAGCTCCCTGCGCCTTTTAACACATGCACATCCAGCAA AAGCAGAGGAGAACCTGGCTGTGATTCAAAGGTAAGGCTGTAATAGTAATGTAATGTAAATAGCTTCATC ATGCACGGCTTGGACATGGTACTGTGTGCATGCAACTGATATTTGTGAATTTGCTCCTATTTATTGTTTC ATGTTTAATTATATTGGTGGCATTAGTGTTTATCTTATTATTTCTGCAATCCTTTTTATTATAAGGCTTA TTATTGGAATATTGAAATTTCAGAGCAGTCTGAAGTTTTATTAGGACCACAAATAGACATATTTTCAGAT...'
>
> # ferritin heavy polypeptide 1 (precursor to impactase)
> # https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/14319
> # Keeps ferritin from growing too long (which is important since it will be suspended on the end of oscillitase)
> Fth1 = 'GATGATATGATAGCTATCTCCAGCCAACCTTCCCTCCCGACCTTTGTTTTCTTCAGGGTTTACAAGCTAG TCCACTGGCTCCATATGAACCTCAGAATCACGACCTGCCAAAGAGACACTGTATTTTCACATCTCTGACT CTGTTGAGTTACAGGGTTAGAGCTGACATTTGTAGTATGGAAGATGACCGACCCTTCAGGAAGATAGCAC CTCCTTTCCCCAATACTTGCTTGGCTTTGTTTCGTGGTATTGGTGATCTTATTACTTGCTACTTGAGTCT CTGCTGCTAAGGTAAGTGAAAATATTTGCTCACTACCATCACCCTCTTGCTGGTCTTCCATCATATTTTT CTGATGGTGGTTACCCTTAGAAAAAAATTGCATGCATTCTACATGTGACAATGACTAGGCTGGACTCCTA CCAGTTTTGTATTGATTTACAGTAATGTTCCTAAAATCAAATGGATATGATATATCCATATTACCTACAG GGTAAAGTTTAATGACTTTTTATGGCTCGCCAGTCTGACTATGTTCTTTCCAGCTCTCCCCAACATGCAC ...'
> # NHEJoin oscillitase-alpha terminal strand to Ferritin piece
> Fth1_splits = random_splits(Fth1, min_len=300, max_len=1000)
>
> # save the combinated sequence
> combined = make_split(4*P680+[FASN, MAPT, TUBA1B, TUBA1C, Fth1_splits]
> with open(sys.argv[1], 'w', enc='base-pairs-only') as f:
>   f.write(combined)
> ```
>
> Note: you'll also need the following dependencies or their codes: RPA, RAD51, LigIV, MRN,  If some of these are in short supply try taxing to a research lab so scientists can finish the job
>
> Once you've transfused the above libraries, you'll want to replicate (but do not transcribe or translate) until you have a few backup copies of the source code.
>
> Then run `transcribe` and `translate` on the output sequences. Putting it togethor, you should have a compilation process like this:
>
> ```
> $ python3 thermotroph.py dna
> $ for i in 1..10000000000; do replicate; done
> $ transcribe dna rna
> $ translate rna proteins
> $ for protein in $(ls proteins); do ./protein; done
> ```
>
> If everything works, something's gone wrong, but congrats for you. You're now the first thermotroph on earth.
> If it doesn't work, try repeating the process 10^15 times or wait until `gcc` and `gdb` come out for synbio.

Scientists keep discovering more fascinating details on how thermotrophs thrive in their unique niche. I haven't had time to write about how the internal network of oscillitase-$\beta$ strands transforms and stores energy in lower-frequency, higher-amplitude vibrations, or how vibrational energy is more important than chemical gradients to these creatures, or how they perform processing on-bar with insects using just a collection of *predictase* enzymes and what that means for genetics and inheritance. But the point is: these creatures are a candidate for thermotropic life and should be considered by any planning to send a magmarine down into the mantle.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pS5VP.png): Couldn't find statistics for magma. But at STP, the ["average speed of the water molecules in the water is approximately 590 m/s"](https://www.verticallearning.org/curriculum/science/gr7/student/unit01/page05.html#:%7E:text=When%20water%20is%20at%20room) and ["the average distance between the water molecules is 0.31 nm"](https://www.google.com/search?q=average+distance+between+water+molecules&oq=average+distance+between+water+mo&aqs=chrome.0.0i512j69i57j0i390l3.5893j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). $0.31nm \div 590 m/s \approx 0.00053ns$.

Comment: Please *do not* answer questions that obviously violate the prohibitions and restrictions of the [help].